# Graphql query is only resolving _id field, the other fields are null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

My GraphQL query is resolving docID and docTitle to null. Though the data is being retrieved from the DB. Only the _id field is being returned. When I console log I can see the data.

GraphQL query

```
query{
  docs{
    docId
    docTitle
    _id
  }
}
```

My resolver

```
const getDocs = async (_parent, _args, context, _info) => {
    const docs = await context.app.models.docs.find()
    return docs
}
```

Docs schema

```
type Docs {
    _id: ID!
    docId: String
    docTitle: String
}
```

On the GraphQL playground, this is what I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "getDocs": [
      {
        "docId": null,
        "docTitle": null,
        "_id": "5e7c9007f4c3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I console log I am able to see data for all the fields

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e7c9007f4c3,
    docId: 'c18c-57e4b5134cbe',
    docTitle: 'cloud',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: Hi there! Please, can you share the `docs` schema?

Comment: @Tunmee I have updated the question with the schema

Comment: I mean the `docs` mongoose schema, not the graphql type. The schema you defined with something like `new mongoose.Schema({ ... })`. I'm asking this based on the assumption that you are using mongoose, let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: @Tunmee Yes, I am using mongoose but without a schema. So when defining my models I am passing the mongoose setting to false to allow me use it without a schema `mongoose.model('docs', new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false }))`

Comment: Ooh, I see. Can you try appending `.toJSON` to the DB query i.e the query should be something like this: `await context.app.models.docs.find().toJSON()` and see if this works. I'm guessing the types of `docId` and `docTitle` returned from the DB are not explicitly strings.

Comment: @Tunmee The query returns an array. I don't think it is possible to append toJSON() to it

Comment: query definition ? is it returning `[Docs]`? even when DB returns data there is filtering to match [query] types

Comment: In that case, try setting the [lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option. so the query is something like this: `await context.app.models.docs.find({}, {}, { lean: true })`

Comment: @Tunmee Thank you, the lean option has worked for me

Comment: Cool. Let me submit that as an answer so others can easily benefit from it and I can also get some SO rep :-).

Comment: Also, to avoid further type issues like this, I would advise that you explicitly create the schema for the `docs` and other data entity, this would make it easy to predict just what type each of the properties should be and casting would be deliberately done where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the types of `docId` and `docTitle` returned from the DB are not explicitly strings, consequently, some type checking is happening somewhere that causes their values to be stripped out of the output `docs` object. Try adding the [lean option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to the query so that each document in the query result is transformed into a javascript object, that should help ensure the values `docId` and `docTitle` are cast down to strings.

Update your DB query to something like this:

```
await context.app.models.docs.find({}, {}, { lean: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) parameter also resolved the query correctly

```
const getDocs = async (_parent, _args, context, _info) => {
return await context.app.models.docs.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { docId:1, docTitle:1 },
    },
])}
```